# Edit legend of an excel chart with EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

Im writing a simple application that takes a text file, converts it to Data Table, performs few operation on it and then converts to Excel Worksheet and draws a chart .
To achieve that I am using EPPlus 4.1.0

Here's the code of the method I use for drawing charts :

```
    public static ExcelPackage DrawChartTwoAxis(this ExcelPackage package)
    {
        if (package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(ws => ws.Name == "Wykresy") != null)
        {
            package.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete("Wykresy");
        }
        ExcelWorksheet worksheetWithCharts = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Wykresy");

        ExcelWorksheet worksheetWithData = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Dane"];

        var numberOfRows = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Dane"].Dimension.End.Row;
        var maxColumnLetter = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Dane"].Dimension.End.Address.ToCharArray()[0];
        var numberofColumns = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Dane"].Dimension.End.Column;

        ExcelChart chart = worksheetWithCharts.Drawings.AddChart("Zgrubny wykres", eChartType.LineMarkers);
        var chartType2 = chart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add(eChartType.LineMarkers);
        chartType2.UseSecondaryAxis = true;

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 2; i <= numberofColumns; i++)
        {
            if (worksheetWithData.Cells[1, i].Text.ToLower().Contains("pttk") ||
                worksheetWithData.Cells[1, i].Text.ToLower().Contains("pt100"))
            {
                var serie = chart.Series.Add(worksheetWithData.Cells[2, i, numberOfRows, i],
                    worksheetWithData.Cells[$"A2:A{numberOfRows}"]);
                serie.Border.Fill.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(rand.Next(0, 256), rand.Next(0, 256), rand.Next(0, 256));
                serie.HeaderAddress = worksheetWithData.Cells[1, i];
            }
            else
            {
                var serie = chartType2.Series.Add(worksheetWithData.Cells[2, i, numberOfRows, i],
                    worksheetWithData.Cells[$"A2:A{numberOfRows}"]);
                serie.Border.Fill.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(rand.Next(0, 256), rand.Next(0, 256), rand.Next(0, 256));
                serie.HeaderAddress = worksheetWithData.Cells[1, i];
            }
        }
        return package;
```

This method is a part of a larger pipeline for processing ExcelPackage and thats why there is no Save() or Dispose() method called.

The point is that on the legend of the chart it creates all series are labled as "Column A", "Column B" etc. despite setting Header property to something else. It works the same no matter if I specify Header name explicitly or by HeaderAdress.

**How to change legend labels to my custom names?** Or if it is impossible with EPPlus - is there any other framework that has such funcionality? Note : I opened created .xlsx file with OpenOffice 4 if that matters, I have no acces to Microsoft Office.

*In addition - I managed to colour my series, even though it was said to be impossible with EPPlus. Can you tell me what exactly do I colour with Border.Fill.Color?*

Answer (score 0):

**1st way)  Loop through all of your columns like that**

```
    //ws is your excel sheet
    //in cells you put the column 
    ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "the column name";
ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "the column name";
```

...

**2nd way)
You can create a DataTable with the column names you want then you fill it with your data and then you load it like below**

```
//ws is your excel sheet
//MyDt is your DataTable
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(MyDt, true);
```